# Set multiple input values from javascript

Tags: javascript

Simple question but I can't find a direct answer. Suppose I have two input fields:

```
<input type='hidden' id='cat' />
<input type='hidden' id='dog' />
```

How can I assign each a different value from Javascript? I know how to do this with one value:

```
<input type='hidden' id='cat' />

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('cat').value='meow' ;
</script>
```

But can't seem to make this happen with two different values.

Comment: how are you trying to do two?  Your sample for doing it with one is straight forward and works fine

Comment: adding document.getElementById('dog').value='woof' ; to your javascript code doesn't work?

Comment: You will have to loop through each hidden fields if those all are of the same type and then you can assign values one by one. But this sort of practice would make any sense.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='hidden' id='cat' />
<input type='hidden' id='dog' />
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('cat').value='meow';
document.getElementById('dog').value='woof';
</script>
```